# How to set a password in a Laravel Envoy script?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-envoy

In Laravel 5.8 using envoy I want to set the password of a user in console command, like

```
envoy run Deploy  --serveruser_password=mypass1112233
```

Having in envoy file:

```
@setup
    $server_login_user= 'serveruser';
    $user_password = isset($serveruser_password) ? $serveruser_password : "Not Defined";


@endsetup


@task( 'clone_project', ['on'=>$on] )
    echo '$user_password password ::';
    echo $user_password;
```

But $user_password output empty in both cases :
1) if serveruser_password is set in command

```
envoy run Deploy  --serveruser_password=mypass1112233
```

2) or it is empty

```
envoy run Deploy
```

But I expected "Not Defined" outputted...

Why error and how correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following.

```php
@setup
    $server_login_user = 'serveruser';
    $user_password = isset($serveruser_password) ? $serveruser_password : 'Not Defined';
@endsetup

@servers(['local' => '127.0.0.1'])

@macro('deploy')
    clone_project
@endmacro

@task('clone_project')
    echo 'The password is: {{ $user_password }}.';
@endtask
```

Please make sure your macro is named "deploy" and not "Deploy." Also, in your echo statement, use curly braces to echo out your set variable. The output will be as follows.

```
$ envoy run deploy --serveruser_password=mypass1112233

[127.0.0.1]: The password is: mypass1112233.

$ envoy run deploy
[127.0.0.1]: The password is: Not Defined.
```